# Bezier MxN Surface in matrix form( with Python and numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, bezier, surface

I am trying to rewrite slow method("bezier_surf_eval") for bezier surface with quick one(in matrix form "bezier_surface_M").

Using this formula:

[image: Q(u, w) = [U][N][B][Mt][W]]

Were [N] and [M] an bezier basis matrix (4x2 degree, because of 5x3 control points),
[U], [W] is surface uv params, [B] - control points

What i do wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import comb


def bern(i, d, t):
    return comb(d, i) * (t ** (d - i)) * (1 - t) ** i


def bezier_matrix(d):
    return np.array([[(-1) ** (i - j) * comb(j, i) * comb(d, j) for i in range(d + 1)] for j in range(d + 1)], int)


BM = [bezier_matrix(i) for i in range(16)]

poles5x3 = np.array([
    [[1.8, -0.3, 0.], [1.8, 0.13, 0.1], [1.8, 0.5, 0.]],
    [[2., -0.3, 0.06], [2.1, 0.1, 0.1], [2.1, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.3, -0.3, 0.1], [2.3, 0.13, 0.2], [2.3, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.4, -0.3, 0.1], [2.5, 0.1, 0.15], [2.5, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.6, -0.3, 0.], [2.6, 0.1, 0.1], [2.5, 0.5, 0.]]])



def bezier_surf_eval(poles, u, v, deg_u, deg_v):
    count_u, count_v = deg_u + 1, deg_v + 1

    co = [0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(count_u):
        for j in range(count_v):
            bu = bern(i, deg_u, u)
            bv = bern(j, deg_v, v)

            pole_co = poles[i][j]
            m = bu * bv
            co[0] += pole_co[0] * m
            co[1] += pole_co[1] * m
            co[2] += pole_co[2] * m

    return co


def bezier_surface_slow(poles, resol=(16, 16)):
    params_u = np.linspace(0, 1, resol[0])
    params_v = np.linspace(0, 1, resol[1])

    count_u, count_v, _ = poles.shape
    du, dv = count_u - 1, count_v - 1

    cps = poles.tolist()

    coords = np.empty((*resol, 3), float)
    for vi, v in enumerate(params_v):
        for ui, u in enumerate(params_u):
            coords[ui, vi] = bezier_surf_eval(cps, u, v, deg_u=du, deg_v=dv)

    return np.array(coords, np.float32)


def bezier_surface_M(cps: np.ndarray, resol=(16, 16)):
    u = np.linspace(0, 1, resol[0])
    v = np.linspace(0, 1, resol[1])

    count_u, count_v, _ = cps.shape
    deg_u, deg_v = count_u - 1, count_v - 1

    u_vec = np.array([u ** i for i in range(count_u)])
    v_vec = np.array([v ** i for i in range(count_v)])

    BM_u, BM_v = BM[deg_u], BM[deg_v]
    return u_vec.T.dot(BM_u).dot(cps).dot(BM_v.T).dot(v_vec)


fig: Figure = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax: Axes3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# ax.scatter(px, py, pz)

# --------------
resol = 16, 16
co = bezier_surface_slow(poles5x3, resol=resol)
x, y, z = co.T
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.gray, linewidth=1, antialiased=False)

# --------------
resol = 16, 16
co = bezier_surface_M(poles5x3, resol=resol)
x, y, z = co.T
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.gray, linewidth=1, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i solved it.
Problem was in bad order for matrices (in method "bezier_surface_M") for dot product. Multiplication with per-axis matrices with correct orders do the job.

Replaced:

```
u_vec.T.dot(BM_u).dot(cps).dot(BM_v.T).dot(v_vec)
```

With:

```
cps_x = cps[:, :, 0]
cps_y = cps[:, :, 1]
cps_z = cps[:, :, 2]

m1 = u_vec.T.dot(BM_u)
m2 = BM_v.T.dot(v_vec)

x = m1.dot(cps_x).dot(m2)
y = m1.dot(cps_y).dot(m2)
z = m1.dot(cps_z).dot(m2)
```

Maybe it can be optimized with np.tensorproduct or something like that, but i`m not as good with numpy and matrices math.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from scipy.special import comb


def bezier_matrix(d):
    return np.array([[(-1) ** (i - j) * comb(j, i) * comb(d, j) for i in range(d + 1)] for j in range(d + 1)], int)


BM = [bezier_matrix(i) for i in range(16)]

poles5x3 = np.array([
    [[1.8, -0.3, 0.], [1.8, 0.13, 0.1], [1.8, 0.5, 0.]],
    [[2., -0.3, 0.06], [2.1, 0.1, 0.1], [2.1, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.3, -0.3, 0.1], [2.3, 0.13, 0.2], [2.3, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.4, -0.3, 0.1], [2.5, 0.1, 0.15], [2.5, 0.5, 0.1]],
    [[2.6, -0.3, 0.], [2.6, 0.1, 0.1], [2.5, 0.5, 0.]]])


def bezier_surface_M(cps: np.ndarray, resol=(16, 16)):
    u, v = np.linspace(0, 1, resol[0]), np.linspace(0, 1, resol[1])

    count_u, count_v, _ = cps.shape
    deg_u, deg_v = count_u - 1, count_v - 1

    u_vec = np.array([u ** i for i in range(count_u)])
    v_vec = np.array([v ** i for i in range(count_v)])

    BM_u, BM_v = BM[deg_u], BM[deg_v]

    cps_x = cps[:, :, 0]
    cps_y = cps[:, :, 1]
    cps_z = cps[:, :, 2]

    m1 = u_vec.T.dot(BM_u)
    m2 = BM_v.T.dot(v_vec)

    x = m1.dot(cps_x).dot(m2)
    y = m1.dot(cps_y).dot(m2)
    z = m1.dot(cps_z).dot(m2)

    return x, y, z


fig: Figure = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax: Axes3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

resol = 32, 32

# --------------
x, y, z = bezier_surface_M(poles5x3, resol=resol)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=cm.gray, linewidth=1, antialiased=False)
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please don't just show "all the code", talk about what was wrong in the original code, and what you changed, so that others who find this post in the future don't need to basically diff your code to find out why it now works. Remember to give ["how to write a good answer"](/help/how-to-answer) a read through - even if it's your own question, others benefit from a good answer =)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).